# ViewPager for gallery

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm building a gallery following [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/) tutorial.Until now i've managed to display the images with swipe function like below

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int Id = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Id = R.layout.farleft;
            break;
        case 1:
            Id = R.layout.left;
            break;
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
```

But i want to display a lot of pictures so i can't crete hundrets of cases for setting hundrets of different layouts.So what options do i have here?Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this way..

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem( final View pager, final int position )
{
    //Note: if you do not have a local reference to the context make one and
    //set it to the context that gets passed in to the constructor.
    //Another option might be to use pager.getContext() which is how its
    //done in the tutorial that you linked.
    ImageView mImg = new ImageView(context);

    /*Code to dynamically set your image goes here.
    Exactly what it will be is going to depend on 
    how your images are stored. 
    In this example it would be if the images
    are on the SD card and have filenames
    with incrementing numbers like: (img0.png, img1.png, img2.png etc...)*/

    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
         Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/img" + position + ".png");
    mImg.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);




    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(mImg, 0);
    return mImg;

}
```

Try link too
https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager

Comment: Thanks, much easier then i thought it would be.

Answer (score 0):

```
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("image_" +
                Integer.toString(position), "id", context.getpackageName();
```

I typed that from heart, so there might be some typo, but I'm sure u understood the concept.